# Value of k so that $ke^x -x$ has one solution

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We are given equation as $ke^x -x$ and we need to get value of k so that it has at least one root. We can rewrite equation as $$ke^x =x$$ for us to get solution graph of $y=x$ and $y=ke^x$ must intersect at one point , so $y=x$ must be tangent to curve and its slope is $1$ and similarly slope of $y=ke^x$ is $ke^x$ which should be 1 , hence $ke^x=1$ but this doest gives us value of $k$ , how else this problem should be done ? Similarly for what $k$ there should be more than 1 root?

Comment: You could study the variations of the function $x \, \mapsto \, ke^{x}-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $x$ you have $e^{x} \neq 0$, so you can divide both sides by $e^x$, you have:

$$k=e^{-x}x$$

Now you can see that horizontal line $y=k$ must intersect graph of $f(x)=e^{-x}x$ at exactly one point $x_0$, so $x_0$ must be global minimum or maximum of $f(x)$. You can check (by calculating derivative), that $f(x)$ hasn't global minimum, but has global maximum at $x_0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You found $ke^x=1$ by considering the slope of the tangent.  But also the tangent must meet the exponential curve, so $ke^x=y=x$ as well.  Together these give that $x=1$ at the point of tangency, and so $k=\frac1e$.